# Wordpress add secondary title and display post only with titles?

Tags: php, wordpress

In my wordpress page I want to add a feature which will allow me to display post in the browsing loop (e.g. by categories) only with main title and secondary title. By default wordpress engine use title and first sentences from post content.

I've installed a "Secondary Title" title plugin to add a this ability however in my post section I just get First Title:Secondary title and post content below it. How can I change it?

Comment: Do you want to display firs title and second title post archive pages?

Comment: yes. Just a first title as a main. And the second title below it instead of first sentences from the post content

Comment: then you can edit your archive file with secondary title